# JNI_CreateJavaVM crash my program without any message or exception

Tags: java-native-interface, mixed

Recently I begin to use JNI in my project.  Here is my code:

```
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

It crashes in `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` and my program aborts without any message or exception.

Visual Studio gives me:

```
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'D:\Develop\Survivor\x86\Debug\SurvivorCore.exe', Symbols loaded.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'D:\Develop\Survivor\x86\Debug\SurvivorLibrary.dll', Symbols loaded.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'D:\Develop\Survivor\x86\Debug\UIAdapterSelector.dll', Symbols loaded.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mscoree.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120_clr0400.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\c90ef9a73ea0044641d31b19023aad61\mscorlib.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Develop\Survivor\x86\Debug\UIAdapterSelector.dll', Symbols loaded.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\1c5fe4cb68f67046baec4c3a854f722f\System.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x4940000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'ImageAtBase0x4ab0000', Loading disabled by Include/Exclude setting.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Unloaded 'ImageAtBase0x4940000'
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wininet.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\userenv.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'D:\Develop\Survivor\x86\Debug\CSharpUI2DImpl.dll', Symbols loaded.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\8efdc7a3726640f79d9333da88accaf8\System.Drawing.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\70c6bf4a51d18b4a9a1805cd48d1caad\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9600.16384_none_7c55c866aa0c3ff0\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\00fc7d14bbb38db00e4103912c041adf\System.Configuration.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\43edd630a9f8cd6ac38c527b106ec94f\System.Xml.ni.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9600.17227_none_dad9452e5bcb7986\GdiPlus.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DWrite.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'D:\Develop\Survivor\x86\Debug\AIAdapterSelector.dll', Symbols loaded.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'D:\Develop\Survivor\x86\Debug\jvm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SurvivorCore.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1404) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x13bc) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1010) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x16a8) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1a0c) has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[3292] SurvivorCore.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[3292] SurvivorCore.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

This code is in a Dll that my Exe loads at runtime. My Exe is a native program and the Dll is C++/CIL (because I am tring to make a universal adapter for other languages). My OS is 64 bit.

I have installed and unistalled JDK & JRE again and again.

I have tried to install JDK 64-bit only, 32-bit only, and both 32-bit and 64-bit.

I want to compile both x86 and x64 versions of my program.

Also, what is the proper way to deploy `jvm.dll`?  I just copy it to my folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have turn to Load jvm.dll dynamicly:

```
typedef jint(JNICALL *pCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void**, void *);

HINSTANCE hInstance = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre1.8.0_25\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll");
pCreateJavaVM CreateJavaVM = (pCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hInstance, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options; 
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
status = CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

And it works...I do not know why...

Comment: For me, even with loadLibrary, it doesn't work.. It hang on line : createJavaJVM

Comment: is it inside DLLMain?

If JNI_CreateJavaVM is called inside DLLMain, it hangs and later can crash.
Its always adviced to keep DLLMain with almost very basic code.

Can have diferent function where we can call JNI_CreateJavaVM.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices

Comment: @Manish OMG, you remind me of my college days. However, it is NOT inside DLLMain. This question is quite old, I do not know if it is suitable for the newer version of Java.

Answer (score 0):

A JVM crash in `JNI_CreateJavaVM()` is commonly caused by JVM's default heap sizes being way too large.  Try using the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` options to tweak the sizes to suit your needs:

```
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));

JavaVMOption options[3];
memset(&options, 0, sizeof(options));

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
options[1].optionString = "-Xms1m"; // 1MB
options[2].optionString = "-Xmx1g"; // 1GB

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
vm_args.nOptions = 3;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

You can specify any command-line option that you can pass to `java.exe`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it still crash...even I use "-Xmx128m"...is it relate to the location of the jvm.dll?

Comment: No. And you are statically linking to the function, so the EXE loader ensures the DLL exists before the EXE starts running.  So something else is going on.