# Unable to use JNI when enabled from within Win32/MFC application

Tags: java, c++, mfc, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use Java functions from within a Visual C++ application by availing of the Java Native Interface, but am not having much luck.

I'm calling the code in a button click handler function within a CDialog, and I get as far as trying to create a Java VM instance and my application throws an access violation exception: "Unhandled exception at 0x0F7D260A (mfc120u.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFF26."
However, when I put my code into a skeleton C++ app containing just a main() function, it all works fine.

As far as I can tell, I've set my project up correctly in Visual Studio 2013. I'm including jni.h from the include directory in my JDK folder, and I'm linking against jvm.lib contained inside my JDK lib folder. I'm using JDK 1.8.0_91 as well.

For what it's worth, here is the code:

```
JNIEnv *env = NULL;
JavaVM *jvm = NULL;
jint res;
  // Initialization arguments
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));

JavaVMOption options[3];
memset(&options, 0, sizeof(options));

options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:/";
options[1].optionString = "-Xms128m"; // 128MB initial heap size
options[2].optionString = "-Xmx1g"; // 1GB maximum heap size

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
vm_args.nOptions = 3;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;
jint status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: Have you tried putting the JVM initialization in `WinMain`, and having `JavaVM *jvm` be a global, file-static or class-static variable?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't try that, I tried putting it in InitInstance() but Ill try what you said. Out of curiosity why do you think it might work there but not where I have the code now ?

Comment: @david: `WinMain` is not accessible to user code in an MFC application. It's baked into the MFC framework. The `CWinApp`'s derived class' `InitInstance` override is the appropriate place to perform application initialization in an MFC application.

Comment: I have more information about what's happening now. The call to JNI_CreateJavaVM is causing my Windows application to exit for some reason. The access violation error above seems to be a side effect of it rather than the main problem. In the stack trace I can see multiple nested calls within jvm.dll and then a call to msvcr100.dll!exit(int code).

Comment: Did you try dynamic linking? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435647/jni-createjavavm-crash-my-program-without-any-message-or-exception

Comment: Yes I did :( I tried toying around with JVM heap sizes as well but that didn't work, I had to give up on using the JNI and invoke my code from the CLI in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I figured this out. Apparently the JNI throws exceptions on startup by design to verify the environment it's running in. See [Exception 0xC0000005 from JNI_CreateJavaVM (jvm.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36250235/exception-0xc0000005-from-jni-createjavavm-jvm-dll?noredirect=1&lq=1).

When I disabled the particular exception in Win32 exceptions in visual studio , it all works fine.